# Why are all my DNS queries received from 127.0.0.1?

Tags: dns

I used the `host` command on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to check my DNS server:

```
host -a www.amazon.com
```

showing this:

```
Trying "www.amazon.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 22892
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.amazon.com.            IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.amazon.com.     60  IN  SOA ns-942.amazon.com. root.amazon.com.        1405660589 3600 900 7776000 60
www.amazon.com.     7   IN  A   72.21.194.212
www.amazon.com.     412 IN  NS  ns-942.amazon.com.

Received 110 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53 in 176 ms
```

Why **Received form 127.0.0.1**?

I've tried different websites, and moved to different locations trying this command.
The DNS server shown is always the same: 127.0.0.1. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IP address 127.0.0.1 means [localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), i.e. it refers to your computer. The DNS response is coming from your computer.

The `host` program, like all other programs on the system, knows which DNS server to query by looking in the file [`/etc/resolv.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/resolv.conf.5.html).

The reason your computer is sending the DNS response is that it is running a DNS cache. The DNS cache software remembers requests, so that if you access the same site multiple times in quick succession (for example, to display a web page with embedded images, Javascript, frames, etc., or display several pages from the same site), only the first request needs to wait for a reply from a distant server, and subsequent requests get a very quick reply from the local machine.

Ubuntu runs [dnsmasq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) as a DNS cache by default. Dnsmasq itself queries a DNS server provided by your ISP; this configuration is normally done dynamically (through [`resolvconf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/resolvconf.8.html): the DNS server is added to the configuration when the corresponding network interface goes up and removed when the interface goes down. Available DNS servers for Dnsmasq are recorded in `/etc/resolvconf/run/interface/*`.

Note that I provide file names for curiosity purposes only. There are very few circumstances where you would want to edit them.

Comment: such a good answer!

Comment: I thought the DNS servers are recorded in etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/

Comment: @BluePython The servers in that directory are the ones used by programs running on this machine. Normally there's only `127.0.0.1`. The DNS servers from the that your machine queries are calculated at runtime based on the available network connections, and they're recorded under /etc/resolvconf/run/interface`. Dnsmasq is the only program that uses this information: applications contact dnsmasq and dnsmasq contacts the external DNS servers.

Comment: sorry not sure I understood. The info at etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/ is used to calculate /etc/resolvconf/run/interface/ ?

Comment: @BluePython No. You need to distinguish two sets of DNS servers: the servers that applications query (recorded in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`), and the servers that the machine queries (recorded in `/etc/resolvconf/run/interface`). On a modern Ubuntu under the default configuration, applications query the locally-running dnsmasq (they know because `/etc/resolv.conf` is built from `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`), and that dnsmasq instance queries the external servers (from information in `/etc/resolvconf/run/interface`).